# Google Sheets Pivot Table Filter How to keep cells that have been filtered out and make it return with zero value

Tags: google-sheets, filter, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot table from this data:

| DATE | TYPE | LOCAL | OUTSIDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-02-2023 | Chocolate | Room 1 |  |
| 10-02-2023 | Milk | Room 1 |  |
| 10-03-2023 | Milk |  | Bakery |
| 10-03-2023 | Milk | Room 2 |  |
| 10-04-2023 | Chocolate |  | Bakery |
| 10-04-2023 | Candy | Room 4 |  |
| 10-05-2023 | Chocolate |  | Gas Station |
| 10-05-2023 | Milk | Room 1 |  |
| 10-06-2023 | Chocolate |  | Bakery |
| 10-06-2023 | Milk |  | Bakery |
| 10-07-2023 | Candy | Room 3 |  |
| 10-07-2023 | Candy |  | Hotel |
| 10-08-2023 | Letter |  | Hotel |
| 10-08-2023 | Milk |  | Hotel |
| 10-09-2023 | Milk | Room 2 |  |
| 10-09-2023 | Chocolate |  | Gas Station |
| 10-10-2023 | Chocolate |  | Bakery |
| 10-10-2023 | Chocolate | Room 4 |  |

I need to count how many of the type goes either local or outside by using google sheets pivot table and putting local column and outside column to the values it will look like this:

ALL TYPES

| DATE | COUNTA OF LOCAL | COUNTA OF OUTSIDE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-02-2023 | 2 | 0 |
| 10-03-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 10-04-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 10-05-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 10-06-2023 | 0 | 2 |
| 10-07-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 10-08-2023 | 0 | 2 |
| 10-09-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 10-10-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| Grand Total | 8 | 10 |

The Problem is when I add a filter on type column, I still need to show all the date even if it doesn't have the type that was in the filter.

CHOCOLATE ONLY

| DATE | COUNTA of LOCAL | COUNTA of OUTSIDE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-02-2023 | 1 | 0 |
| 10-04-2023 | 0 | 1 |
| 10-05-2023 | 0 | 1 |
| 10-06-2023 | 0 | 1 |
| 10-09-2023 | 0 | 1 |
| 10-10-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| Grand Total | 2 | 5 |

I'm trying to make the pivot table to show all the dates while the filtered type can be shown as zero like this:

CHOCOLATE ONLY

| DATE | COUNTA of LOCAL | COUNTA of OUTSIDE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-02-2023 | 1 | 0 |
| 10-03-2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 10-04-2023 | 0 | 1 |
| 10-05-2023 | 0 | 1 |
| 10-06-2023 | 0 | 1 |
| 10-07-2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 10-08-2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 10-09-2023 | 0 | 1 |
| 10-10-2023 | 1 | 1 |
| Grand Total | 2 | 5 |

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1avnjXKGCsiHxFuozLG55en9mJkltczsv-CeGdscTbjM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi! I added the link to my sample spreadsheet, hope you guys can help me